# I try to know whether my amazon SNS endpoint getting notification or not in PHP

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, http-post, amazon-sns, file-get-contents

Tried to get the amazon sns response on my http endpoint. Whenever i trigger ses send mail service to a non-existent email to get a bounce mail it should send the notification to the amazon SNS endpoint. To check this I tried to write a code as below but didn't get response for it. NOthing has bee shown in the code. Please help where i am doing wrong

```
    $file = 'posttest.php';
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    `enter code here`$fp = fopen($file, 'w') or die('Could not open file!');
    $arr = json_decode($json, true);
    $var = $arr['Message'];

fwrite($fp, $var) or die('Could not write to file');
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to see the apache access logs if the endpoint is being hit. For me, a csrf error was causing the post call to my endpoint to fail. I used csrf_exempt decorator (I use Django) and it worked fine.

You can also set an email endpoint in sns topic, and it will send the notification to both http endpoint and to the email. If you get the email, surely the http endpoint is also being hit.